# Can I define more than one Schema.org 'ItemAvailability'?

Tags: product, schema.org, availability

Can I define two values of [`ItemAvailability`](http://schema.org/ItemAvailability) as part of the [`Offer` properties](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products#offer_properties) of my product mark-up?

I.e. I'd like to show `InStock` AND `InstoreOnly`.

Google's structured data testing tool doesn't flag an example code containing both values, but I can't find "live" examples.

Answer (score 1):

Using `InStock` should suffice according to [Google Merchant Center Help](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6386198?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=6386199), as using `InStoreOnly` implies:

> Out of stock (useful if the item is out of stock on your site but available at physical retail shops)

Using both attributes does not throw up any errors in:

- [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)
- [Structured Data Linter](http://linter.structured-data.org/)

But I would only use `InStock`.

---

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://www.productontology.org/id/Microwave_oven" />
  <span itemprop="name">Kenmore White 17" Microwave</span>
  <img itemprop="image" src="kenmore-microwave-17in.jpg" alt='Kenmore 17" Microwave' />
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <!--price is 1000, a number, with locale-specific thousands separator
    and decimal mark, and the $ character is marked up with the
    machine-readable code "USD" -->
    <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">$</span>
    <span itemprop="price" content="1000.00">1,000.00</span>
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock"/>In stock
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStoreOnly"/>In store only
  </div>
  Product description:
  <span itemprop="description">0.7 cubic feet countertop microwave. Has six preset cooking categories and convenience features like Add-A-Minute and Child Lock.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no experience with Google Merchant stuff, but I guess they care only about web stores, right? So from this perspective, it makes sense to understand `InStoreOnly` as "out of stock" -- because it can’t be bought online. But OP wants to convey that the product can be bought in the physical store, so it’s certainly relevant information for other consumers (i.e., those that don’t only care about web shops).

Comment: @unor Google Merchant Center also allows you to advertise products, which are only available in your offline store.